# Qt4.8 -> Qt5 large latency difference with QTabWidget switch

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qt4.8

I decided to transform my Qt4.8 project to Qt5. (with visual 2010 and Vaadin)

Now (Qt5), when I launch my program, there is 5 or 10 secondes of latency when I switch some tabWidget (with the same code, in qt4.8 there is no latency)

in my tab, I have many buttons in a flowLayout.

someone have an idea ? Qt5 tabWidget have a big diffence with Qt4.8 tabWidget ?

Comment: I don't think it's the tab widget.. You could use a profiling tool like `Valgrind` for Unix or `Very Sleepy` for Windows

Comment: @TimMeyer 
There is the result of very sleepy (I don't know if it visible sry :s)

RtlInitializeExceptionChain,54.53,77.90,70.00,100.00,ntdll,
DispatchMessageW,7.79,13.091,10.00,16.80,USER32,
Sleep,7.79,7.79,10.00,10.00,KERNELBASE
MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx,2.44,2.44,3.14,3.14 USER32
free,1.862071,1.862071,2.390330,2.390330,MSVCR100D,
malloc,1.72,1.72,2.21,2.21,MSVCR100D,
QTimer::isSingleShot,0.99,7.78,1.27,9.99,Qt5Cored
QCss::StyleSelector::selectorMatches,0.15,7.78,0.20,9.99,Qt5Guid
operator new,0.15,0.15,0.19,0.19,MSVCR100D
QWidget::normalGeometry,0.13,7.78,0.17,9.99,Qt5Widgetsd